# Are w3.org docs correct?

Tags: alpha

I'm referring to this section: https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#simplealphacompositing

Considering the formula `co = Cs x αs + Cb x αb x (1 - αs)` the docs state then, that `co` is the

> the premultiplied pixel value after compositing

I would argue that this is not the case, since in [this article](http://jcgt.org/published/0004/02/03/paper.pdf) the resulting color is depicted with a capital C and in the case of premultiplied version, the lower case is used (`c`). I'm not really sure if this is the case, it's not too obvious from both docs and the article. So, is the result of  `co = Cs x αs + Cb x αb x (1 - αs)` really a premultiplied value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the statement in the W3C doc is correct. You can tell because the background term includes premultiplication by the background alpha αb. If it were non-premultiplied, it wouldn't have an αb in it.

Comment: Yes, "does not contribute to the final color of the pixel" would be a good way to say it, or maybe "zero alpha meaning that the color has no influence on the final pixel color".